# Dimension of a finite vector space over a finite field and composition series

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $F$ be a finite field. Suppose $V$ is a finite vector space over $F$. Show that dim$_F(V) = \ell(V)$, where $\ell(V)$ denotes the length of the composition series of $V$.

I have no clue in this one, how are normal subgroups in a finite vector space? Maybe I was thinking about hyperplanes, but I don't know how to attack the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All subgroups are normal vector spaces are abelian.

Also your statement is valid for finite fields $F$ where the number of elements is a prime (as opposed to a power of a prime)

You must be aware that every vector space has a basis.

Take a basis $v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_n$. Now define $V_j$ to be the span of first $j$ vectors of this basis. Now look at the series
$$ V_0=\{0\}\subset V_1\subset V_2\subset \cdots \subset V_n=V$$
Now you should be able to complete the arguments.